# spherical coordinates of $\rho, \theta$ , and $\phi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The spherical coordinates of $(-3, 4, -12)$ are $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$. Find $\tan \theta + \tan \phi$.

So would this be $\tan 4 + \tan (-12)$?
Not sure, so I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: The last question you posed was 23 minutes earlier, also on trig questions. Are we doing your homework?

Comment: Nope, the given coordinates are Cartesian. You have to convert to spherical (or at least to the tangents of the angles).

Comment: Perhaps a better phrasing of the problem would be this: The point with rectangular coordinates $(-3, 4, -12)$ has *spherical* coordinates $(\rho, \theta, \phi)$. Find $\tan \theta + \tan \phi$."

Comment: @ninjagirl you asked a similar question not long ago. Do you actually understand the concepts of spherical coordinates? If not, which concept do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

The given point $(-3, 4, -12)$ has $x=-3;\;y=4;\;z=-12$

The transformation equations are
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}x&=\rho\,\sin \theta \,\cos \phi \\y&=\rho\,\sin \theta \,\sin \phi \\z&=\rho\,\cos \theta \end{aligned}\right. $$

so you get
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}\rho\,\sin \theta \,\cos \phi &=-3\\\rho\,\sin \theta \,\sin \phi &= 4\\\rho\,\cos \theta&=-12 \end{aligned}\right. $$
If you divide LHS of 2nd and 1st equation you get

$$\frac{\rho\,\sin \theta \,\sin \phi}{\rho\,\sin \theta \,\cos \phi}=\frac{\sin\phi}{\cos\phi}=\tan\phi=-\frac{4}{3}$$
Knowing the value of $\tan\phi$ we can get $\sin\phi=-\dfrac{4}{5}$

Apply the same trick to 2nd and 3rd equation we get

$$\frac{\rho\,\sin \theta \,\sin \phi}{\rho\,\cos \theta }=\tan\theta\sin\phi=-\frac{4}{12}=-\frac{1}{3}$$
Plugging $\sin\phi=-\dfrac{4}{5}$
we have

$$-\frac{4}{5}\,\tan\theta =-\frac{1}{3}\to \tan\theta=\frac{5}{12}$$

The  result is then

$$\tan\theta+\tan\phi=\frac{5}{12}-\frac{4}{3}=-\frac{11}{12}$$

Hope this helps